# помогите с GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

День добрый. Есть вот такой селект. Есть поле `MODIFIED_ON`( в нем хранится дата ), которое хранится в базе, оно связано с полем `PRODUCT`. Поле `MODIFIED_ON` со временем может изменится. Соответвенно при объединении таблиц, надо взять самое последнее значение `MODIFIED_ON`. Я делаю это группировкой по `MAX()`, но видимо не совсем верно, так как все равно данный приходят то новые, то старые. Как изменить запрос,чтобы данные из `MODIFIED_ON` всегда были максимально новыми?

```
SELECT 
ID,
BrandName,
Consumption,
datetime,
KDF,
Value = MEAN_TARGET,
PRODUCT,
LastDate = MAX(MODIFIED_ON)


FROM 
(SELECT  
        ID = Parm.ID,
        BrandName = Phys.PRODUCT,
        Consumption = Phys.MEAN,
        datetime = Phys.DATETIME,
        KDF
                END     

    FROM ( SELECT * FROM [xxx].[xxx].[PARAMETER] 
    WHERE ID  = 5 ) AS Parm 

    INNER JOIN 

    (SELECT * FROM [xxx].[xxx].[PHYSICAL_DATA]

            WHERE 
                  REPLACE(MACHINE, 'KDF0', 'KDF') IN (@Equipment)
                  AND DateTime 
                  BETWEEN DateAdd(Minute,450,(@DateTime))  
                  AND DateAdd(minute,1170,(@DateTime))
                  AND PARAMETER = 5   
        ) AS Phys
        ON Parm.ID =  Phys.PARAMETER

                WHERE PARAMETER = 5  


)  SelectDay1

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT MEAN_TARGET, PRODUCT ,MODIFIED_ON   FROM [xxx].[xxx].[SPEC] 


WHERE PARAMETER = 5 

) AS Spec

ON SelectDay1.BrandName = Spec.PRODUCT


GROUP BY 
ID,
BrandName,
Consumption,
datetime,
KDF,
MEAN_TARGET,
PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 1):

Группировка и использование функции `max` выглядет правильно. 
Исходя из того, что Вы используете группировку для получения даты следует то, что в таблице `spec` находится несколько записей для одного и того же `product` но с разной датой `modified_on`. Учитывая это и то, что для выборки данных из таблицы `spec` используется фильтр по атрибуту `parameter` можно предположить то, что для разных значений `parameter` в таблице существую разные записи для одного и того же `product` но с разной максимальной датой.

Пример этого предположения можно посмотреть [здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cbda/16). Если поменять в условие запроса на `spec.parameter = 2` то получится другая максимальная дата.